# python IDLE stack viewer hangs with bigger data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-idle

I am trying to debug a script using IDLE (python 2.7 under Bodhi Linux).
When debugger encounters a big list containing thousands of lists, and I try to open stack-viewer, it hangs.

Is this a known issue or do I need to do something to address this?

Thanks.

Comment: Only my opinion, but I think that IDLE internal debugger is hardly useable for non trivial scripts. If I wanted to build complex Python programs I would rely on a better IDE like [Eric-ide](https://eric-ide.python-projects.org)

Comment: @Serge Ballesta , I am also inclined to think like what you said. BTW, apart from eric, which is your personal choice considering less dependency?

Comment: Unfortunately asking for tools is explicitely off topic here. But a question had been asked on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16246)

Comment: Thanks @Serge Ballesta

Comment: Stack Viewer is intended to get more stack information than tracebacks give after an exception has stopped execution.  It should perhaps be called Stack Trace.  It is a known issue https://bugs.python.org/issue23544  that it eventually disables the user process if invoked while code is running in the user process.  This includes while debugger is running, which it partly does in the user process.  Invoking Stack Viewer before "import time; time.sleep(10)" returns ">>>" is sufficient.  Try turning debugger off first.  1000s of lists might be a separate problem.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Thanks for your input. I was actually impressed by the simplicity of IDLE for debugging. No major dependency / tweaking. I hope the enthusiastic developers fix this bug.